# enabling ssl in apache with cloudfare

Tags: apache, ssl

I have enabled

use `HTTPS` always in Cloudflare and that's working.

Now, coming to Apache, I am on AWS AMI and this is what `httpd.conf` looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName *.aonesalons.com
   DocumentRoot  /var/www/dist/
   <Directory /var/www/dist/>
        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName *.aonesalons.com
   DocumentRoot  /var/www/dist/
   SSLEngine      on
   SSLCertificateFile        /home/ec2-user/aonesalons.com.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile     /home/ec2-user/aonesalons.com.key

   <Directory /var/www/dist/>
        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It worked just fine on port 80, however with https, it shows default test page of apache server on AWS AMI.

You can try with `demo.aonesalons.com`. I am probably missing something very basic here. Can I get some help, please?

Comment: mmm....what happens if you leave only 443 vhost in config file?

Comment: There is maybe another `<VirtualHost *:443>` somewhere in your other .conf files (perhaps the default one in ssl.conf); if there is, just remove it

Comment: Awesome. worked. Thanks